# Encoding problems with node-gdal

Tags: javascript, gdal

I am using node-gdal. I want to interpret S57 (.000) and print it in [key: value] format.
An error has occurred : Hangul(Korean language) is broken.

[image: screenshot]

Languages ​​other than Korean will be displayed normally.
All eclipse settings are OK.

The code to extract the value is shown below.

```
layer.features.forEach(function(feature) {    
    feature.fields.get(AcronymName);
}
```

I need your help.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the RECODE_BY_DSSI option to ON in your gdal configuration code.
This option is available since GDAL 1.10

[More details on S57 Gdal driver page](http://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html)

> RECODE_BY_DSSI=ON/OFF: (OGR >= 1.10) Should attribute values be recoded to UTF-8 from the character encoding specified in the S57 DSSI record. Default is OFF.

This "forces" use of UTF-8 encoding for text decoding, that could save your display problem

Comment: This answer needs more details, i.e. _why_ would setting that flag make a difference. References to external links are not as good as explaining in detail here, because the external link might go away in the future.